# Pandas/Python read file with different separators

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text-files

I have a .txt file as follows:

```
columnA;columnB;columnC;columnD
2022040200000000000000000000011    8000702   79005889  SPECIAL_AGENCY
```

You can observe that the names of the columns are separated by a semi column `;`, however, row values, have different separators. In this example, `columnA` has 3 spaces, `columnB` has 3, `columnC` has 2, and `columnD` has 7.

It is important to clarify, that I need to keep the spaces, hence the “real” separator is the last space.

Considering I have a schema, that tells me for each column what is the amount of spaces (separators?) I have, how can I turn it into a pandas dataframe?

Comment: do all rows have fixed space gaps between columns?

Comment: no, updated, and thanks for the clarification! I have a schema that tells me for each row what is the separator

Comment: so one row can occupy multiple lines (as shown in your post)?

Comment: Is that line wrap in the file, or just a formatting mistake in typing the question?

Comment: Is the `LONDON` line part of the previous line, or a new line? What column does it go into?

Comment: No. For each row, there could be a different separator. Let's say that between column A and B there are 5 spaces. Then, between column B and C there are 3.. and so on. You can see it from this point of view: each row has a maximum number of characters, hence this number is the separator.

Comment: @savayu just formatting

Comment: There should be a 5th column name as well, or am I mistaken?

Comment: `SPECIAL_AGENCY  
     LONDON` should go to `columnD` or there is a `columnE` ?

Comment: It seems to me that the number of spaces is irrelevant. The first 3 space-delimited tokens belong to columnA, columnB and columnC respectively. Then everything else in the line goes into columnD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use a double *regex* separator with (`|`) and [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) :

```
df = pd.read_csv("/tmp/file.txt", sep=";|(?<=\d)\s+(?=\B)", engine="python")
```

Output :

```
print(df)
​
                           columnA  columnB   columnC                       columnD
0  2022040200000000000000000000011  8000702  79005889   SPECIAL_AGENCY       LONDON
```

NB: If needed, you can add [`pandas.Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) to clean up the extra (`\s`) in the `columnD`.

Comment: Does this solution keep the spaces as well? Or it trims out everything?

Comment: If you mean by that, the whitespaces between for example `SPECIAL AGENCY` and `LONDON`, yes they will not be stripped (_as you can see in the output I shared_). Also, my code is based on the format of your example, so if you failed to describe your actual dataset, I'm not sure that you'll get the expected output.

Answer (score 4):

The following should work, however it has the downside of reading the whole file into memory first before creating the dataframe.  That could pose a problem if your file is large.

```py
In [17]: data = Path("data.txt").read_text().splitlines()

In [18]: hdr = data[0].split(";")

In [19]: df = pd.DataFrame([row.split() for row in data[1:]], columns=hdr)

In [20]: df
Out[20]: 
                           columnA  columnB   columnC         columnD
0  2022040200000000000000000000011  8000702  79005889  SPECIAL_AGENCY
```

Comment: There is no 5th column in my example. Apologies for the typo, but I don’t see a new line in my snippet

Comment: @robsanna okay, thanks for the clarification. In that case the answer by Timeless should work for you (accept it if so).